# Pass window.location to Flask url_for

Tags: javascript, python, url, flask

I'm using python.On my page when an anonymous user goes to the sign in page, I want to pass a variable to the backend so it indicates where the user is coming from ( send the URL).

So when the user clicks on this anchor link:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('account.signin') }}">Sign in</a>
```

I want to send current URL of the page where the user is currently.

```
<script>
 var current_url = window.location.href;
<script>
```

I thought to send it like this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('account.signin', current_url="window.location.href") }}">Sign in</a>
```

But I can't use javascript code inside url_for or how can I pass it?

Comment: Are u using Flask or Django Framework?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`request.path`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.path) to get the path while rendering the template.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('account.signin') }}?next={{ request.path }}">Sign in</a>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. This is a very interesting way to do it! I have some documents there generates new URL based on documents name,and then the URL changes without refreshing the page, from base url to specific url. For those this function takes the base URL or the last URL that is refreshed. Is there any way to fix this, like is in javascript a timeout?

Comment: It looks like your page has some javascript code that modifies the URL on the fly. You can use the javascript code provided in marcusshep's answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Django.

In your view you can return the previous location that the User can from:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def foo(request, *a, **kw):
    # sign in user
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Or with Jquery:

Add an ID to the link.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('account.signin') }}" id="signin">
```

Then add the next parameter and redirect the browser to the new url.

```
$("#signin").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    window.location = $(this).href + "?next=" + window.location.href;
}
```

should produce something like: `url/for/signin?next=prev/location`

In your view you can access that next variable like so:

```
def foo(request, *a, **kw):
    next_url = request.GET["next"]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but when I click on sign in link my url looks like this http://0.0.0.0:5000/account/signin?next=window.location.href`  so window.location.href code is not getting current url, it is acting like string?

Comment: why is this happening, please help?

Comment: because it's just url. i think it's gonna be like `{{ url_for('account.signin') }}?next={{ url_for('current') }}` and of course `url_for('current')` should return current route

Comment: I'm using Flask. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the `request` object at its best, since it does provide a [`headers`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.headers) dictionary which has all request headers, quoting from flask's Docs:

> `headers`
>
> The incoming request headers as a dictionary like object.

Now, one of the headers elements is the [`HTTP_Referer`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), which is :

> The HTTP referer (originally a misspelling of referrer[1](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.headers)) is an HTTP
>   header field that identifies the address of the webpage (i.e. the URI
>   or IRI) that linked to the resource being requested. By checking the
>   referrer, the new webpage can see where the request originated.

Finally, you can access it from `flask` as you would access any dictionary item:

```
>>> print('Referer is {}'.format(request.headers.get('Referer')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.path` to get the current URL path (you can also use `request.full_path` which includes the query string part of the current URL path), but no need to construct the query string by yourself, just pass it to `current_url`.

Any keyword parameters pass to `url_for` that isn't a URL variable will become a query parameter automatically:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('account.signin', current_url=request.path) }}">Sign in</a>
```