# Window.location.href with url_for() in flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have an html page with Javascript Attached to it. I have a Button. When it's clicked It redirects to another page using
`window.location.href`
And since iam using flask I Used url_for()
`window.location.href ="{{ url_for('routeName')}}"`

But it's Not Working Flask Says That The Requested url is not found. How can I Make url_for work with window.location.href?

Comment: Can you share some code with us?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass window.location to Flask url\_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862640/pass-window-location-to-flask-url-for)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<a href="{{ url_for('routeName') }}?next={{ request.path }}">Sign in</a>
```

`request.path` is getting the path of the current page. You don't even need the any `js` you can add it to the button's element. [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862640/pass-window-location-to-flask-url-for). I did upload an answer because I wasn't sure if this is exactly what you need since you didn't share any code with us.